# Crear un toggle button en delphi 7

Tags: delphi

Hay alguna forma de crear un `Toggle Button` o `Toggle Switch` en Borland Delphi 7?

[image]

Lo mas parecido que encontré es el `TAdvSmoothSlider` pero no tengo esos componentes y lo que utlizo como check box son `DBCheckBox` pero quisiera implementar algo como un `toggle`.

Es posible? o hay alguna forma de implementarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Yo creo que hay varias opciones.

Por un lado creo que puedes usar **clases sobrepuestas**, para "repintar" el componente y utilizar dos imágenes (una para cada estado) corresponsientes a los 2 estados del componente.  Para ello podrías basarte en un `TCheckBox`.

Este artículo, que en antiguo y válido para versiones viejas de Delphi, te puede servir de base. La explicación es clara y simple:
https://cgarcia.blogspot.com/2006/03/alternativas-los-skins.html

Por otro lado puedes derivar el componente (`TCheckbox`) y redefinir alguno de los mensaje que se utiliza para pintar y utilizar la misma técnica anterior. "Repintar" el fondo del componente con 2 imágemnes segun el estado.

```
procedure WMEraseBkGnd(var Message: TWMEraseBkGnd); message WM_ERASEBKGND;
```